# Use of Graph api to post a feed with @mentions

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'd like to post on user's wall from my iOS app. The message I am posting may contain another user's name as a link (same as when we use @ on facebook). This is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my message @[%@:1:%@]", facebookManager.userId,facebookManager.userName], @"message",nil];
```

but this code doesn't work. Does any one know if graph api supports @mention? I didn't find a document to negate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in Facebook with @mention ability using stream.publish?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5923434/how-to-post-in-facebook-with-mention-ability-using-stream-publish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does *not* support that.

There are several older questions regarding that topic here on SO, but they all come to the conclusion that it is not possible.